# efficient fuzzy string-matching

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

I am striving to find an efficient way to match phoneme strings (with some errors) to orthographic sentences with fuzzy logic.  My problem is that I seems to run out of memory even on my 64GB machine due to the very large search space.

for example I have an input of:

```
sil s r eh d m ae ch ih ng iy t ae ih n ae d l sil
```

which I would like to give me the sentence (or at least as close as possible):

```
thread matching yarn in tapestry needle
sil th r eh d m ae t ch iy ng y aa r n ih n t ae p ih s t r iy n iy d l sil
```

currently I am using fuzzywuzzy where I first try for whole matches and if not the best partial matches on sentence chunks which I am running multiple times to get bigger chunks so that I don't overload the memory and eventually get my partial (par_sents) into by best_sents.  Here is my code so far:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from os import sys

rec_in = sys.argv[1]
candidates = sys.argv[2]
best_sents = sys.argv[3]
par_sents = sys.argv[4]

fuzz_list=[]
fuzz_par_list=[]
sorted_list = []
f1 = open(rec_in, 'r')
f2 = open(candidates, 'r')
f3 = open(best_sents, 'a')
f4 = open(par_sents, 'a')
lines_1 = f1.readlines()
lines_2 = f2.readlines()

for line_1 in lines_1:
    line_1 = line_1.strip()
    for line_2 in lines_2:
        line_2 = line_2.strip()
        fuzz_full = fuzz.ratio(line_2, line_1)
        fuzz_list.append(str(fuzz_full) + "|" + str(line_2))  

#found = False
for i in range(0, len(fuzz_list)):
    string = fuzz_list[i]
    score = string.split('|')[0]
    phrase = string.split('|')[1]

    if score == "100":
        f3.write(phrase + '\n')
        found = True
        print "found best"
        print "exiting... "
        exit()
    else:
        for line_1 in lines_1:
            fuzz_par = fuzz.ratio(phrase, line_1)
            if fuzz_par > 0:
                fuzz_par_list.append(str(fuzz_par) + "|" + str(phrase))


for x in sorted(fuzz_par_list, key =convert, reverse=True):
    f4.write(x + '\n')
```

My partial matches which become the next rounds candidates go something like this:

```
68|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ah s l iy p ih ng k ae p s l
68|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ih n
67|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n
66|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ah s eh k ih n d t w ih ch t
64|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n d aw n ih n b ih k ah r ih ng
64|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n s ah ch ah d ih z ae s t ah r
63|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ey jh ih n s iy hh ay ah r d ah
60|th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ih k s p r eh sh ih n ih n dh ah
60|ah s l iy p ih ng k ae p s l th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ih n
60|s ah ch ah d ih z ae s t ah r th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ih n
...
```

I am wondering if anyone could help me with efficiency. Are there any better packages than fuzzywuzzy or is it just my code that needs work?